# Error showing images in applet in browser

Tags: java, image, applet

I'm new to Java Applets and I have a little problem.
I need to load and display images in applet loaded in browser.This is part of the code i'm using to display image:

```
            Panel first=new JPanel();   
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(new URL(path),"Dell_laptop.jpg");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Image img = getImage(url);
            ImageIcon fimg = new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel(fimg);
            first.add(jLabel1);
```

So when it's working in eclipse, it's working flawless.But when i'm trying  to load this same applet in HTML page, it's not working.Applet is loaded,but images aren't shown.Path is correct, checked it.

Comment: does other components in the applet loaded in browser ?

Comment: I'm using button in the applet, and on click it should show me the images and some text. But no action is performed on click.I tried with wrong path for images, it shows me only the text, but when path is correct there is no action.

Comment: `url = new URL(new URL(path),"Dell_laptop.jpg");`  ..it never crossed your mind that he value of `path` might be relevant to this?!?  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Show the structure of the server (the path from the root of the domain) that contains `Dell_laptop.jpg` ..

Comment: .. 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: It's a college project. So i tried a lot of combinations and I found this:images are shown only with absolute path and if they are in the same directory as class and html file. But images should be in another folder and i should use absolute not relative path. I'm not using server it's all local.

Comment: Guessing on your words "Path is correct" it looks like you use real file system path. It should work in eclipse since it's not browser. But when you use browser everything is internet based and it's not path - it's  link. So, if, for example, your applet is on the page http://me.example.com/test/App.html then "path" should be http://me.example.com/test/Dell_laptop.jpg to something like this. And these urls you should check for avaiability to be sure they exist. Then you can say that "Path is correct"